# Selenium: Do not wait even for initial html

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to use selenium to test a webpage where the initial html contents builds up in a "streaming" fashion.

As simple example, assume that the webpage html is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="p1">foo</p>
    <p id="p2">bar</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

and that the
webserver sends everything up to including `#p1` immediately, then waits for 10s, then sends the rest of the page.

I would basically like to open that page in selenium, "manually" wait until the id `#p1` exists,
check that `foo` is in the page text (or html) so far but `bar` is not; wait for 10s and then check that `bar` is here.

It seems that this is not covered by "Page loading strategy": According to [the docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/) (and to my attempt), even `none` "waits until the initial page is downloaded".

*Question:* Is there a "Page loading strategy" that allows me to continue before the html is loaded? Or is there some option for / alternative to the usual navigation command that lets me immediately continue with selenium? (Such as: Instead of navigate to the page, simulate entering the url in the address bar and pressing return, or whatever..)

Comment: As work around you can use driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); . Once you call driver.get("utl") If page is not loaded in 1 second it will throw TimeOut exception . You can catch that . So page load is interrupted in 1 second

Comment: thank you, the suggested workaround works for me. Would you like to turn it into an answer?

Comment: Sure . added in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work around . We can interrupt the loading of page by using [page load timeout](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-page-load-timeout)

Page load timeout - Provides the timeout limit used to interrupt an explicit navigation attempt.

By Default value is set to '300,000' milliseconds

In Java

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
driver.get("url")
```

driver.get() - > It will throw timeout exception if page is not loaded in 1 second. You can catch the exception and continue with other operations.